# Constantly diminishing free space on fedora 17

Tags: linux, fedora, xfce

I don't know how to explain this other than to say that my computer seems to magically run out of free when it runs for a while.

The output of `df -h .` oh my home direction is below

```
/dev/mapper/vg_vmadiath--dev-lv_home   50G   47G     0 100% /home
```

When I run `sudo du -cks * | sort -rn | head -11` on /home I get the following output. I got this from [Decreasing free space on Fedora 12](https://superuser.com/questions/268196/decreasing-free-space-on-fedora-12)

```
32744344    total
32744328    vmadiath
16  lost+found
```

If I restart my system things seem to fix themselves and I'm left with about 20 or 25GB of free space.

I'm running XFCE with XMonad as my window manager under fedora 17. Programs I'm running include the XFCE terminal, grep, find, firefox, eclipse, libre-office writer, zsh, emacs.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I'll gladly give you any other output you might need.

Comment: So, now you know the problem is `/home/vmadiath`. So now repeat that command to figure out which directory inside `/home/vmadiath` is growing.

Comment: Thats what I did when running the second command. As you can see, vmadiath is only 32GB, while the partition is already full.

Comment: Then it's probably deleted files. As root, while the disk space is in use, execute this command: `lsof | grep deleted`

Comment: I'm not sure how, but this fixed itself once I upgraded to XFCE 4.10. Thanks for all your help. David if this ever happens again I'll be sure to run that command.

Comment: Hi David, the problem has reared it's ugly head again. I ran the command you mentioned, and it gave me the following output (I ran this as root). I've also put the output at http://pastebin.com/0ZN76bb6

crond       861           root    3uW     REG               0,16           4      19499 /run/crond.pid (deleted)
xfrun4     1355       vmadiath  txt       REG              253,1      120448      50920 /usr/bin/xfce4-appfinder.#prelink#.ZewGnk (deleted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by a bug in emacs 24.0.95 when opened in daemon mode. Emacs had written 38GB of log data to the .xsession-errors file, which was causing my disk space to disappear. If you run into this problem, just upgrade emacs. I ended up compilnig 24.1.1 from source.

To see if emacs is causing this, open the .xsession-errors file, and see if you see a lot of lines with the text

```
Back to top level.
```

Answer (score 0):

Glad that you found the issue.  Here's a link to a script that I put together to find big files. The .snapshot dir is a filter for how we do NFS around here, but doesn't hurt, so I left it in.

[dir_usage_info](http://pastebin.com/Bu9sL1VZ)